# Import not loaded in time, can't call constructor at top level (Browserify, ES6)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, browserify

At the top level of my code, I have:

```
import Range from '../classes/Range';

let _data = Range.create({ tl: { /*stuff*/ }, br: { /*stuff*/ } });

export default class OtherClass { //uses _data
}
```

Javascript is giving me an error of the form "Cannot read property create of undefined." It appears that Browserify is importing Range later than the time at which I'm using it at the top level. How do I get around this problem (or ideally, make Browserify import it at an earlier time)?

Comment: What is in your `Range` class? You probably aren't exporting properly.

Comment: My Range class is just "export default class Range { stuff }". I don't think that's wrong...

Comment: If that is literally all your code, this should work. The only way an import like this would fail is if potentially you have circular dependencies in your deps. Does your `Range` in any way depend on `OtherClass`? It seems like we'll need a simple reproducible case.

Comment: ^ I have seen this issue with circular references...